# How to run a script at the start up of Ubuntu?

Tags: shell, ubuntu-11.04

I want to run some Java programs in the background when the system boots in Ubuntu. I have tried to add a script in /etc/init.d directory but failed to start a program. i.e programs are not started. What should I do for that?

Comment: Should be moved to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: or move to superuser

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Answer (score 95, accepted):

First of all, *the easiest way to run things at startup is to add them to the file `/etc/rc.local`.*

Another simple way is to use `@reboot` in your crontab. Read the cron manpage for details.

However, if you want to do things properly, in addition to adding a script to `/etc/init.d` you need to tell ubuntu when the script should be run and with what parameters. This is done with the command `update-rc.d` which creates a symlink from some of the `/etc/rc*` directories to your script. So, you'd need to do something like:

```
update-rc.d yourscriptname start 2
```

However, real init scripts should be able to handle a variety of command line options and otherwise integrate to the startup process. The file `/etc/init.d/README` has some details and further pointers.

Comment: But where should my java file placed? I have created simple java program with infinite loop. then javac and java command put in /etc/rc.local then I have reboot my system but program was not running. what to do?

Comment: Thanks its being done. I have created a service in /etc/init.d and then started service in rc.local.

Comment: `rc-update` does not exist in Ubuntu. Use `update-rc.d <basename> start|stop NN runlevel [runlevel]` instead. Replace `<basename>` with your script name, `NN` with the order in which the script runs (within the specified runlevel). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Debian_Linux for more info about run levels in Ubuntu/Debian

Comment: Or `update-rc.d yourscriptname defaults` to create both startup and kill scripts all at once.

Comment: I don't see a mention of 'boot' anywhere on both cron's and crontab's man pages.

Comment: For people who need to startup apps at boot-up... Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/140713/668801) out!