# How to start the java (.jar) application at boot time of ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, daemon

I made simple java application which has a submit button on clicking which the application starts executing .I have to deploy it at Ubuntu System.Now Sir ,As per my need i have to start the execution automatically as soon as System boots without clicking any
submit button.

I saved my application at Desktop  of Ubuntu.

Comment: This should be asked on askubuntu.  There are many ways to do this, depending on your specific requirements ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link to see how to run a script during Ubuntu startup
[How to run a script at the start up of Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu)

The script could be a java -jar jarname call.
Off course java has to be installed.