# How to run .jar file on start up in ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have written a javafx media player.I want to run this on start-up. The mediaplayer.jar file is located at Desktop.The player plays the files inside a data folder which is in the same directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a script at the start up of Ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758317/how-to-start-the-java-jar-application-at-boot-time-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Raedwald.
I studied the post you mentioned and I finally resolved it.

Here the steps I did.

```
startapp.sh

#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/usr/local/bin/vedioplayer.jar
```

created the above script and saved it in /etc/init.d
make sure you allow execution of the shell script.

```
  sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/startapp.sh
```

After that run the follwing command

```
  sudo update-rc.d startapp.sh defaults 98 02
```

Also you can add the script to Startup Applications list from Applications.