# How to create a shell script for open browser with particular ip ?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to create a shell script for open a new browser link with particular ip like 192.168.1.25:87 at startup for my ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2):

**I hope that helped**

> [Clean way to launch the web browser from shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124556/clean-way-to-launch-the-web-browser-from-shell-script)

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1
[[ -x $BROWSER ]] && exec "$BROWSER" "$URL"
path=$(which xdg-open || which gnome-open) && exec "$path" "$URL"
echo "Can't find browser"
```

Answer (score 0):

To run  a script in Ubuntu at start up see the following link.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

As for the script to open a browser there are many ways of doing this, use the  one that works for you. Replace the url with the IP that you want to open.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -n $BROWSER ]; then
  $BROWSER 'http://wwww.google.com'
elif which xdg-open > /dev/null; then
  xdg-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null; then
  gnome-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
# elif bla bla bla...
else
  echo "Could not detect the web browser to use."
fi
```

Comment: not worked at startup,only in direct excution of shell

Comment: @user3459140 Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu for execute at startup.Also look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: yes,it is worked like text write task to a document but open browser task not worked at startup.MY /etc/rc.local  code is given below   echo "iam worked ok" >> /home/eyenet/Desktop/foo/mydoc
&
if which xdg-open > /dev/null; then
  xdg-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null; then
  gnome-open 'http://wwww.google.com'
fi

Comment: When the computer boots, it runs some startup scripts, but this is before there is a user logged in to an X11 session. Probably you should hook this into your personal X11 session startup, not the system's boot scripts.

Comment: how to hook into personel x11 session startup?