# How to Run Script File on Ubuntu Every time Ubuntu Starts

Tags: shell, ubuntu, registerstartupscript

I have Make one Script File that i need to run every time when ubuntu starts so how can i put that file on startup. not in start up folder that will run every time but i need to find other way to run that script every time how can i do that?

i have used some of the reference but its not working.
[How to run a script at the start up of Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run following command to create new cronjob entry

```
$ crontab -e
```

It will open text editor.(For first time it will ask you to select default text editor). Add your script with @reboot keyword

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Save the file. That's it.

Comment: But i am getting options when i am writing crontav -e

Comment: That options are for choosing your default editor. Choose `nano`, its the easiest.

Comment: i did that and what i have to do means that script path?

Comment: location of your script. Assume that your script `test.sh` is in `/home/krishna/scripts/` directory then add `@reboot /home/krishna/scripts/test.sh` into your cronjob editor.

Comment: i did that and now shell i go to restart pc?

Comment: How did you verified? Try to add one more line `@reboot (date >> /var/tmp/reboot.txt)` and check the content of `/var/tmp/reboot.txt`. It is tested.

Comment: but why add this line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56628/discussion-between-sanket-parmar-and-krishna).