# Linux Ubuntu execute jar file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar, startup

I created a jar file **store.jar** and placed it inside: /etc/init.d  directory ( I wanted to execute it on startup)
I created a script **test.sh** (inside /etc/init.d) with following code:

```
java -jar store.jar
```

After that, I executed:

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/test.sh start 2
```

by following this thread:

[How to run a script at the start up of Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339555/how-to-run-a-script-at-the-start-up-of-ubuntu)

If I execute the script from inside the /etc/init.d directory, it works fine.

```
/etc/init.d: sh test.sh
```

### Problem 1.

If I'm on a different folder and run test.sh, it says **unable to access store.jar**

```
/home/abc: sh /etc/init.d/test.sh
```

### Problem 2.

Nothing happened on ubuntu startup. I mean where can I see the reason why script did not run.

I hope you understand my question.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

Why don't you `cd /etc/init.d/` before calling `java -jar store.jar`. That way, not matter where you are, it will find the `store.jar` file.

**Problem 2**

Less of an answer but why don't you pipe the output from executing the jar to a file. That will tell you if there are any issues in the jar. Furthermore, you could `echo "This script ran" > ~/test.log` to check if the script even ran at startup.

Comment: Hi mikeecb, thanks for the quick reply. Yes I'm able to run from inside /etc/init.d but I wanted to run by doing -classpath switch. I'll do the second one by piping the output. Thanks again